# My Android socket.io is sending data but not receiving data

Tags: android, socket.io

My issue is that my socket is sending data but not receiving. I'm pasting my code here - where have I gone wrong? When I'm checking as Log then message sending show but my socket is not receiving the data. I am using here default socket URL.

My code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button sendBtn;
    private TextView textView;

    private com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://chat.socket.io");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
    }

    private EditText mInputMessageView;
    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    String username;
                    String message;
                    try {
                        username = data.getString("username");
                        message = data.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // add the message to view
                    addMessage(username, message);
                }
            });
        }

    };
    private void addMessage(String username, String message) {
        textView.setText(username+message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInputMessageView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mInputMessageView);
        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
        mSocket.connect();

sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        attemptSend();
    }
});
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mSocket.disconnect();
        mSocket.off("new message", onNewMessage);
    }
    private void attemptSend() {
        String message = mInputMessageView.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            return;
        }

        mInputMessageView.setText("");
       mSocket.emit("new message", message);

    }

}
```

Comment: Which data should be receivd? And how?

Comment: username and message...i'm sending data in String message = mInputMessageView.getText().toString().trim(); and data will receive username and nessage

Comment: Here i am using a textview which help to display received message

Comment: You have a client for Android. This client sends something to a server. What is send? And does the receiver, the server, receive what is send? And after that: does the server send something? What? And is is received by the client? You should much better tell what should happen and what happens instead.

Comment: `String message = mInputMessageView.getText().toString().trim();`. Bad! We cannot see what the user types in. You should use a hard coded message instead. So then we can talk about it.